# Integral between limits 0 and pi

Tags: definite-integrals

Please Integrate $$
\int_0^\pi \frac 1{(a^2\sin^2x + b^2 \cos^2)^2}\, dx$$ between limits 0 and pi.
I have tried it multiple times but i keep falling into the tan inverse trap.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int\frac{dx}{a^2\sin^2x+b^2\cos^2x}=\frac1{ab}\int\frac{\frac a{b\cos^2x}}{1+\left(\frac ab\tan x)^2\right)}dx=\frac1{ab}\arctan\left(\frac ab\tan x\right)+C\ldots$$

The above's based on the basic

$$\int\frac{f'(x)}{1+f(x)^2}dx=\arctan f(x)+C$$

Comment: The denominator is squared as a whole. Hence the above substitution does not help.

Comment: Yeah...too bad that when I addressed this question the question was unedited and pretty blurry. BTW, the answer above has no substitution at all, and the same algebraic trick shown there can probably help for the squared denominator...

Comment: I tried that but it didn't help.